# How to get iframe name from one JSP page to another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, iframe

My `Form.jsp`:

```
<iframe id="results" name="results" value="resultsvalue" style="display:   none;"  width="100%" height="240" frameborder="1">
</iframe>
```

I want to access the `iframe` name in another JSP page.

My `Form2.jsp` contains button:

```
<input type="submit" name="myButton"  value="Execute MxV Scenario" OnClick="" style="float:right;width:200px;height:30px;text:Submit;border:1px solid;border-radius:10px;border-color:grey;">
```

I want to access `iframe` name on button click.

Comment: It sounds like something that would be done on the client side (javascript).

Comment: ok.Then how to get iframe name using js in jsp page which is in another page

Comment: you can't actually

Comment: what are You trying to do?`

Comment: i want to show/hide iframe while clicking on button.But the button in one jsp page and iframe in another jsp page

Comment: are they displayed in different pages/tabs?

Comment: no those need to display in same page

Comment: but you don't know the name of the iframe?

Comment: i know the iframe name but i am unable to call  that name from another page

Comment: So the iframe is in My Form.jsp, and the content of the iframe in My Form2.jsp?

Comment: no contents iframe in another jsp i want to display on iframe while clicking on button

Comment: in that case, you just need to get the iframe on the click of the button (in javascript that is)

Comment: yes i need to call the iframe while click on button in javascript

Answer (score 0):

So you would do something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResults() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("results");
    iframe.style.display = "block";
    iframe.src = "Results.jsp"; // or whatever
}
</script>
```

and then:

```
<input type="submit" name="myButton" onclick="displayResults()" ... />
```